# Sequentially displaying a list of game objects

Tags: c#, unity3d

A chat background is created and `text[0]` is displayed with a button created under it. The created button iterates thru `text[]` and finds the next one to display setting all others to inactive and the current one to active.
`text[]` can hold a `GameObject` with just a text block, or up to 4 buttons.

The code works fine and I just know that it needs a lot of improvement.

[This](https://gyazo.com/edf5f2f6ac220f3b206751fc896f068a) is what the code looks like when being used in-game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Dialogue  {
    //the ui of the game
    static GameObject ui = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas");
    //the ui's manager
    static UIManager m = ui.GetComponent<UIManager> ();
    //a list of gameobjects containing text and buttons
    List<GameObject> text = new List<GameObject>();
    //the 'press to continue' button
    private GameObject cont = null;
    //the currently displayed text[]
    int currentlyDisplayed = -1;


    //opens the chat display and creates the first text[0] and  the continue buttons
    public void displayChat(int npc){
        var page = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Interfaces/Chat");
        if (m.dia) {
            Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets ();
            return;
        }
        m.dia = (GameObject)m.instantiate (page);
        m.dia.name = page.name;
        m.dia.transform.SetParent(ui.transform);
        m.dia.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().position = new Vector2(0f,145f);
        m.dia.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (Screen.width/2,145);
        text = (findText (npc));
        displayText (0);
        var b = CreateButton();

        if (m.c) {
            if (m.c.activeInHierarchy)
                m.c.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
    //displays text[displayed]
    void displayText(int displayed){
        currentlyDisplayed = displayed;
        text[displayed].SetActive(true);
    }
    //iterates threw the text[] to display the next chat dialogue
    void iterateText(){
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++) {
            if (text [i].activeInHierarchy) {
                text [i].SetActive (false);
                break;
            }
        }
        currentlyDisplayed++;
        if (currentlyDisplayed >= text.Count) {
            m.closeChat ();
            text.Clear ();
            return;
        }
        text [currentlyDisplayed].SetActive (true);
        if (text [currentlyDisplayed].name == "Text") {
            if (cont) {
                if(!cont.activeInHierarchy)
                    cont.SetActive (true);
            }
        }else if (text [currentlyDisplayed].name == "Button") {
            if (cont) {
                if(cont.activeInHierarchy)
                    cont.SetActive (false);
                }
            }
    }
    //finds what text should be displayed
    List<GameObject> findText(int npc){
        List<GameObject> t = new List<GameObject>();
        switch(npc){
        case 1:
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "There are times when you get suckered in  ", 16, Color.white,true,false));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "by drugs and alcohol and sex with women-mmkay.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "But its when you do these things too much.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "That you've become an adict and must get back in touch!", 16,  Color.white,true,false));//
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "You can do it its all up to you mmmmmmmkay", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "Mhmmmm", 16, Color.white,true,false));
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText(),"button3",() => iterateText(),"button4",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText(),"button3",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "Ha hahahaha hahahahaha", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<t.Count;i++){
            t [i].SetActive (false);
        }
        return t;
    }
    //hex to color
    Color HexToColor(string hex)
    {
        byte r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(2,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(4,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        return new Color32(r,g,b, 255);
    }
    //creates a button
    private GameObject CreateButton(){
        GameObject button = new GameObject("button");
        RectTransform trans = button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2 ((Screen.width/2)-20, 25);
        button.transform.SetParent (m.dia.transform);
        button.transform.localPosition = new Vector2((button.gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x/2),-126);
        var b = button.AddComponent<Button> ();
        var img = button.AddComponent<Image> ();
        var nav = new Navigation ();
        nav.mode = Navigation.Mode.None;
        b.navigation = nav;
        b.targetGraphic = img;
        img.color = HexToColor ("F1D678FF");
        var col = b.colors;
        col.normalColor = Color.white;
        b.colors = col;
        var t = CreateText (b.transform, (Screen.width/2)-20, 25, "Click here to continue...", 14, Color.blue,false,false);
        t.GetComponent<Text> ().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        b.onClick.AddListener(() => { iterateText(); });
        button.tag = "Continue";
        cont = button;
        return button;
    }
    //adds 2 options
    private GameObject addOptions(string one, Action fOne,string two, Action fTwo){
        var parent = new GameObject ("Button");
        parent.transform.SetParent (m.dia.transform);
        CreateButton (one,() => fOne(),-22).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (two,() => fTwo(),-48).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }
    //adds 3 options
    private GameObject addOptions(string one, Action fOne,string two, Action fTwo,string three, Action fThree){
        var parent = new GameObject ();
        parent.transform.SetParent (m.dia.transform);
        CreateButton (one,() => fOne(),-22).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (two,() => fTwo(),-48).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (three,() => fThree(),-74).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }
    //adds 4 options
    private GameObject addOptions(string one, Action fOne,string two, Action fTwo,string three, Action fThree,string four, Action fFour){
        var parent = new GameObject ();
        parent.transform.SetParent (m.dia.transform);
        CreateButton (one,() => fOne(),-22).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (two,() => fTwo(),-48).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (three,() => fThree(),-74).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        CreateButton (four,() => fFour(),-100).transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }
    //creates a button with custom name and function at a selected y
    private GameObject CreateButton(string but1, Action function, int y){
        GameObject button = new GameObject("button");
        RectTransform trans = button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2 ((Screen.width/2)-20, 25);
        button.transform.SetParent (m.dia.transform);
        button.transform.localPosition = new Vector2((button.gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x/2),y);
        var b = button.AddComponent<Button> ();
        var img = button.AddComponent<Image> ();
        var nav = new Navigation ();
        nav.mode = Navigation.Mode.None;
        b.navigation = nav;
        b.targetGraphic = img;
        img.color = HexToColor ("F1D678FF");
        var col = b.colors;
        col.normalColor = Color.white;
        b.colors = col;
        var t = CreateText (b.transform, (Screen.width/2)-20, 25, but1, 14,  Color.white,true,false);
        t.GetComponent<Text> ().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        b.onClick.AddListener(() => { function(); });
        return button;
    }
    private GameObject CreateText(Transform canvas_transform, float x, float y, string text_to_print, int font_size, Color text_color, bool shadow, bool outline)
    {
        GameObject UItextGO = new GameObject("Text");
        UItextGO.transform.SetParent(canvas_transform);
        RectTransform trans = UItextGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
        //trans.anchorMin = new Vector2(0,0);
        //trans.anchorMax = new Vector2(1,1);
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (x, y);
        Text text = UItextGO.AddComponent<Text>();
        if (outline) {
            Outline o = UItextGO.AddComponent<Outline> ();
            o.effectColor = Color.black;
        }
        if (shadow) {
            Shadow s = UItextGO.AddComponent<Shadow> ();
            s.effectColor = Color.black;
        }
        text.text = text_to_print;
        text.fontSize = font_size;
        text.color = text_color;
        text.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource (typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
        return UItextGO;
    }
}
```

This is how I initially call this file:

```
var d = new Dialogue ();
d.displayChat (1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you confirm whether the code works as intended? I ask because I noticed that `dispalyChat()` seems to be misspelled.

Comment: Haha thanks for pointing that out, and i edited the original post. But it works fine, just want help improving it. Also thanks for the welcome !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**

As BKSpurgeon mentioned, your naming is going to make it hard to understand this code in a few months (maybe even weeks).

```
if (m.c) {
    if (m.c.activeInHierarchy)
        m.c.SetActive (false);
}
```

What is `m.c`?
What is `m.dia`?

**Inconsistencies**

You have bits of code where your `()` and `[]` have a space before them when calling a function or indexer. Personally, I find this very confusing, I've never seen this done (Let me know if there's a reason for this, I'm curious). If there is no reason, I would suggest not having a space before them. *Examples below.*

```
if (text [i].activeInHierarchy) {
    text [i].SetActive (false);
    break;
}

m.dia.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().position = new Vector2(0f,145f);
```

Another inconsistency is your use of `var`. This implicitly determines at compile-time what the type is, so if your code is obvious what it is returning (e.g. `var i = 0;` or `var transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();`) then I would recommend using it.

**Unused Code**

```
private GameObject cont = null;
cont = button;
```

Is this used for anything?

**Repetitive Code**

You have a few places where you repeat code. Typically programmer's aim for minimal repetition. For more information read up on the `DRY` principal (stands for "Don't repeat yourself").

*This:*

```
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "There are times when you get suckered in  ", 16, Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "by drugs and alcohol and sex with women-mmkay.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "But its when you do these things too much.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "That you've become an adict and must get back in touch!", 16,  Color.white,true,false));//
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "You can do it its all up to you mmmmmmmkay", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "Mhmmmm", 16, Color.white,true,false));
```

*Could Be:*

```
var textWidth = Screen.width / 2 - 35; // No need for parenthesis, It calculates all the same (order of operations).
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "There are times when you get suckered in  ", 16, Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "by drugs and alcohol and sex with women-mmkay.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "But its when you do these things too much.", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "That you've become an addict and must get back in touch!", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "You can do it its all up to you mmmmmmmkay", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, textWidth, 130, "Mhmmmm", 16, Color.white,true,false));
```

*Psst...You have a typo: `adict` should be `addict`.*

Consider making a list/array of the texts you use for dialog so that it's easier to see the text as a whole, then loop through each one adding it as you loop (see below).

*Then you could do something like this:*

```
List<GameObject> findText(int npc)
{
    var screenWidth = Screen.width / 2 - 35;
    var textDialogs = new List<string>()
    {
        "There are times when you get suckered in  ",
        "by drugs and alcohol and sex with women-mmkay.",
        // ...
        "Mhmmmm"
    };

    var t = new List<GameObject>();
    switch (npc)
    {
        case 1:
            foreach (var textDialog in textDialogs)
            {
                t.Add(CreateText(m.dia.transform, screenWidth, 130, textDialog, 16, Color.white, true, false));
            }
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText(),"button3",() => iterateText(),"button4",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(addOptions("button1",() => iterateText(),"button2",() => iterateText(),"button3",() => iterateText()));
            t.Add(CreateText (m.dia.transform, (Screen.width/2)-35, 130, "Ha hahahaha hahahahaha", 16,  Color.white,true,false));
            break;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++) {
        t[i].SetActive(false);
    }
    return t;
}
```

**CreateButton()**

Here's a list of the following changes I've made:

- 1. Added whitespace (Line breaks) for a bit of readability. This doesn't affect performance at all.
- 2. Made use of [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).
- 3. Potentially reduce unnecessary calls (see below).
- 4. Used `var` consistently (aka when not necessary to use explicit form).
- 5. Removed unnecessary spaces before `()` and `[]` (see 2nd suggestion in answer).
- 6. Tried to be a bit more explicit on naming. I don't claim to be the best at naming, so take the name changes with a grain of salt.

*(2) This:*

```
var nav = new Navigation ();
nav.mode = Navigation.Mode.None;
b.navigation = nav;
```

*(2) Could Be:*

```
b.navigation = new Navigation()
{
    mode = Navigation.Mode.None
};
```

*(3) This:*

```
button.gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x/2
```

*(3) Could Be:*

```
var trans = button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
...
trans.sizeDelta / 2
```

*(Please correct me if I'm wrong, but those are the same component right?)*

*Bringing it all together:*

```
private GameObject CreateButton(string but1, Action function, int y) {

    var screenWidth = Screen.width / 2 - 20;
    var buttonObject = new GameObject("buttonObject");

    var trans = buttonObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Screen.width, 25);

    // Again, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that
    // "buttonObject.gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>()" == "trans" right?
    buttonObject.transform.SetParent(m.dia.transform);
    buttonObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(trans.sizeDelta.x / 2, y);

    var button = buttonObject.AddComponent<Button>();
    button.navigation = new Navigation()
    {
        mode = Navigation.Mode.None
    };

    var image = buttonObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    button.targetGraphic = image;
    image.color = HexToColor("F1D678FF");

    button.colors.normalColor = Color.white;

    // NOTE: You could add alignment as a parameter but that's soley your decision. That is a lot of parameters.
    // NOTE: Notice the consistent spacing after each comma. It may seem silly but it adds readability.
    var text = CreateText(button.transform, screenWidth, 25, but1, 14, Color.white, true, false);
    text.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;

    button.onClick.AddListener(() => { function(); });

    return buttonObject;
}
```

**Conclusion:**

There's a lot here, and some of it may not entirely apply in your case, but with a grain of salt (I sound like a broken record) I hope this will help you.

Comment: There are definitely a lot of things I missed or just didn't have time to mention, so if you don't receive anymore answers, I highly recommend applying these suggestions the best you can (and want) and posting another review/question with the updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I will start reviewing/comparing and implementing your suggestions here soon! I really appreciate the time you have spent helping me!

Comment: Yes! Trans can equal the rectTransform in the way that you have suggested. The only thing is you didn't add the .x on sizeDelta. I should do that tho, you are correct! And i may misunderstand a little. Do you mean i should try to always use var 'var button = buttonObject.AddComponent<Button>();' or should i use 'Button button = buttonObject.AddComponent<Button>();' Also with the spacing after '()' and '[]' was due to my editor auto adding it in haha. Im also a little confused with your CreateText. Would using that allow the game to still work as shown in the gyazo?

Comment: And im usingthe' var cont' to store the 'press to continue' button in a variable so i can access it easily in my code. Specifically for the iterateText part where it sets cont to active or inactive

Comment: In regards to the 'var' suggestion, I was stating that if the right-side makes it obvious what the datatype is then use 'var' otherwise don't. So in the case of the button, I would use var since in plain text it's obvious that it'll be a component of type `Button`.

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of an editor adding spacing like that. I find that very odd. I made a mistake with the `CreateText` suggestion, I mistakenly was under the assumption you could add multiple objects to the `t.Add(..)` function. I have corrected it to be a better use-case.

Comment: just so you know, iv added most of your suggestions and re asked the question :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133009/choosing-creating-setting-an-npc-dialogue