# Choosing/creating/setting an NPC dialogue - follow-up

Tags: c#, unity3d

Initial post: [Sequentially displaying a list of game objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132812/sequentially-displaying-a-list-of-game-objects)

This file creates a dialogue box and sets the chat history box too inactive. It finds which NPC dialogue to display, creates the list and sets which index of the `dialogueList` should be active.

[This](https://gyazo.com/6d3d4dc9b75c5797af9015eac0e3e70f). is what the code looks like being ran in-game.

Initially I call this file with:

```
Dialogue.Instance.displayDialogue("trader",0);
```

I would like to look at achieving the same thing but using `Enumerator`s. From my novice understanding, it would run more efficiently as such.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Dialogue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton of Dialogue
    /// </summary>
    private static volatile Dialogue instance = null;
    private static object syncRoot = new object();
    private Dialogue() { }
    public static Dialogue Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new Dialogue();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private static UIManager ui = UIManager.instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// a list of gameobjects containing text and buttons
    /// </summary>
    private List<GameObject> dialogueList = new List<GameObject>();

    /// <summary>
    /// the 'press to continue' button
    /// </summary>
    private GameObject continueButton = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// the currently displayed dialogueList[]
    /// </summary>
    private int currentlyDisplayed = -1;

    public static GameObject dialogue = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Getter Setter for continueButton
    /// </summary>
    private bool continueButtonActive
    {
        get { return continueButton.activeInHierarchy; }
        set { continueButton.SetActive(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the type of the currently displayed dialogue
    /// </summary>
    private string typeOfCurentlyDisplayed
    {
        get { return dialogueList[currentlyDisplayed].name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// opens the dialogue display and creates the first dialogueList[0] and  the continue buttons
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="npc_chat_to_display">The npc chat to display</param>
    /// <param name="dialogue_to_display">Where too start the dialogue display</param>
    public void displayDialogue(string npc_chat_to_display, int dialogue_to_display)
    {
        var page = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Interfaces/Chat");
        if (dialogue)
        {
            page = null;
            Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
            return;
        }
        dialogue = (GameObject)ui.instantiate(page);

        dialogue.name = page.name;
        dialogue.transform.SetParent(ui.gameObject.transform);
        var trans = dialogue.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.position = new Vector2(0f, 145f);
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, 145);
        dialogueList = (findDialogue(npc_chat_to_display, dialogue_to_display));
        createButton();
        if (ui.chatBox)
        {
            if (ui.chatBox.activeInHierarchy)
                ui.chatBox.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The trader npc
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The dialogueList of the trader</returns>
    private List<GameObject> trader()
    {
        return new List<GameObject>(){
        createText("Hello! Welcome to the game!"),
        createText("Would you like to trade?"),
        //iterateDialogue is just in place to test function firing.
        addOptions("Yes!", () => iterateDialogue(), "No!", () => iterateDialogue()),
        createText("Oh ok!")
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// finds what text should be displayed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="npc_chat_to_display">The npc chat to display</param>
    /// <param name="dialogue_to_display">Where too start the dialogue display</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<GameObject> findDialogue(string npc_chat_to_display, int dialogue_to_display)
    {
        var range = new List<GameObject>();
        switch (npc_chat_to_display)
        {
            case "trader":
                range.AddRange(trader());
                break;
        }
        currentlyDisplayed = dialogue_to_display;
        for (int i = 0; i < range.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != dialogue_to_display)
                range[i].SetActive(false);
            else
                range[i].SetActive(true);
        }
        return range;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// iterates threw the dialogueList[] to display the next chat dialogue
    /// </summary>
    void iterateDialogue()
    {
        dialogueList[currentlyDisplayed].SetActive(false);
        currentlyDisplayed++;
        if (clearDialogue())
            return;

        dialogueList[currentlyDisplayed].SetActive(true);
        setContinueButon();
    }

    private bool clearDialogue()
    {
        if (currentlyDisplayed >= dialogueList.Count)
        {
            ui.closeChat();
            dialogueList.Clear();
            currentlyDisplayed = -1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// sets the active state of the continue button
    /// </summary>
    private void setContinueButon()
    {
        if (continueButton)
        {
            switch (typeOfCurentlyDisplayed)
            {
                case "Text":
                    if (!continueButtonActive)
                        continueButtonActive = true;
                    break;
                case "Button":
                    if (continueButtonActive)
                        continueButtonActive = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// converts HEX to RGB
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hex"> the HEX to convert</param>
    /// <returns> the RGB being returned</returns>
    private Color HexToColor(string hex)
    {
        byte r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        return new Color32(r, g, b, 255);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds twoo button option
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="button_one_name">The name of the first button</param>
    /// <param name="function_one">The first function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_two_name">The name of the second button</param>
    /// <param name="function_two">The second function to be called</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private GameObject addOptions(string button_one_name, Action function_one, string button_two_name, Action function_two)
    {
        var parent = new GameObject("Button");
        parent.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        createButton(button_one_name, () => function_one(), -22).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_two_name, () => function_two(), -48).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds twoo button option
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="button_one_name">The name of the first button</param>
    /// <param name="function_one">The first function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_two_name">The name of the second button</param>
    /// <param name="function_two">The second function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_three_name">The name of the third button</param>
    /// <param name="function_three">The third function to be called</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private GameObject addOptions(string button_one_name, Action function_one, string button_two_name, Action function_two, string button_three_name, Action function_three)
    {
        var parent = new GameObject();
        parent.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        createButton(button_one_name, () => function_one(), -22).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_two_name, () => function_two(), -48).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_three_name, () => function_three(), -74).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds twoo button option
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="button_one_name">The name of the first button</param>
    /// <param name="function_one">The first function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_two_name">The name of the second button</param>
    /// <param name="function_two">The second function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_three_name">The name of the third button</param>
    /// <param name="function_three">The third function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="button_four_name">The name of the fourth button</param>
    /// <param name="function_four">The fourth function to be called</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private GameObject addOptions(string button_one_name, Action function_one, string button_two_name, Action function_two, string button_three_name, Action function_three, string button_four_name, Action function_four)
    {
        var parent = new GameObject();
        parent.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        createButton(button_one_name, () => function_one(), -22).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_two_name, () => function_two(), -48).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_three_name, () => function_three(), -74).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        createButton(button_four_name, () => function_four(), -100).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
        return parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a button
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private GameObject createButton()
    {
        var button = new GameObject("button");
        var trans = button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2((Screen.width / 2) - 50, 25);
        button.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        button.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width / 4, -126);
        var b = button.AddComponent<Button>();
        var img = button.AddComponent<Image>();
        b.navigation = new Navigation()
        {
            mode = Navigation.Mode.None
        };
        b.targetGraphic = img;
        img.color = HexToColor("F1D678FF");
        var col = b.colors;
        col.normalColor = Color.white;
        b.colors = col;
        var t = createText(b.transform, (Screen.width / 2) - 50, 25, "Click here to continue...", 14, Color.blue, false, false);
        t.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        b.onClick.AddListener(() => { iterateDialogue(); });
        button.tag = "Continue";
        continueButton = button;
        return button;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// creates a button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="button_text">The text to be displayed on the button</param>
    /// <param name="function">The function to be called</param>
    /// <param name="y">The local Y location of the button</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private GameObject createButton(string button_text, Action function, int y)
    {
        var button = new GameObject("button");
        var trans = button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2((Screen.width / 2) - 50, 25);
        button.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        button.transform.localPosition = new Vector2((Screen.width / 4), y);
        var b = button.AddComponent<Button>();
        var img = button.AddComponent<Image>();
        b.navigation = new Navigation()
        {
            mode = Navigation.Mode.None
        };
        b.targetGraphic = img;
        img.color = HexToColor("F1D678FF");
        var col = b.colors;
        col.normalColor = Color.white;
        b.colors = col;
        var t = createText(b.transform, (Screen.width / 2) - 50, 25, button_text, 14, Color.white, true, false);
        t.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        b.onClick.AddListener(() => { function(); });
        return button;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a text gameObject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="canvas_transform">The parent of the gameObject</param>
    /// <param name="x">The X size of the button</param>
    /// <param name="y">The T size of the button</param>
    /// <param name="text_to_print">The text to be displayed</param>
    /// <param name="font_size">The size of the font</param>
    /// <param name="text_color">The color of the text</param>
    /// <param name="shadow">Does the text have a shadow</param>
    /// <param name="outline">Does the text have an outline</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the GameObject</returns>
    private static GameObject createText(Transform canvas_transform, float x, float y, string text_to_print, int font_size, Color text_color, bool shadow, bool outline)
    {
        var UItextGO = new GameObject("Text");
        UItextGO.transform.SetParent(canvas_transform);
        var trans = UItextGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2(x, y);
        var text = UItextGO.AddComponent<Text>();
        if (outline)
        {
            var o = UItextGO.AddComponent<Outline>();
            o.effectColor = Color.black;
        }
        if (shadow)
        {
            var s = UItextGO.AddComponent<Shadow>();
            s.effectColor = Color.black;
        }
        text.text = text_to_print;
        text.fontSize = font_size;
        text.color = text_color;
        text.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
        return UItextGO;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a text gameObject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text_to_print">The text to be displayed</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the GameObject</returns>
    private static GameObject createText(string text_to_print)
    {
        var UItextGO = new GameObject("Text");
        UItextGO.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        var trans = UItextGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        trans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
        trans.sizeDelta = new Vector2((Screen.width / 2) - 50, 130);
        var text = UItextGO.AddComponent<Text>();
        var s = UItextGO.AddComponent<Shadow>();
        s.effectColor = Color.black;
        text.text = text_to_print;
        text.fontSize = 16;
        text.color = Color.white;
        text.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
        return UItextGO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one quick tip, typically in C# local variables and parameters are named using camelCase and don't typically include underscores.

Comment: Good to know, i need to go read an in depth article on naming in c#

Comment: If you go to the C# tag wiki you will find a link to the .NET naming guidelines.

Comment: Damn those comments.. your variable names should be descriptive enough comments or further explanation should be redundant.

Comment: The only reason i have so many discription of parameter names is because of visual studios allowing me to read about the functions at other sections of code. Also the only reason its detailed as much as it is, is so other people can read it and understand it without having to read the code. telling someone to not describe their code threw descriptions is pretty stupid IMO. Alsooooo the fact i can minimize the whole description block. It doesn't matter how detailed i chose to make it.

Comment: I believe what denis was getting at was that "button_one_name" is descriptive enough and "The name of the first button." is a comment that adds no value (AKA redundant).

Comment: No i understand what he was saying. But if i'm posting the codes for other to read, and visual studio's auto fills that out for me. Why not use it. Seems stupid to tell someone to not use a shovel and dig with their hands

Comment: Hmm if the person is not even checking the code why bother explaining the names of the variables ? Write clean and readable code the user should have no problems going through it. If he is at the point where he is looking at the code he should have enough knowledge to understand it, unless you are doing tutorials or something. The comparison with the shovel is not in place.

Comment: The only reason i added the description of the function at all was because i was posting it for review on this site. but i appreciate your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . You have a lot of magic numbers you should do something about that use `enum`, `const` variables, etc. It's really hard for someone that wasn't sitting beside you while you programmed this to understand they're purpose.

2 . You have a lot of parameters which isn't something crucial, but that usually that means most of them can be grouped and put in classes, after that simply pass the entire class as parameter. You don't seem to be passing `button_text` or `function` alone they always go together that's something you should group in some way. Having them stored somewhere will make it much easier for you to do repetitive operations over them. Maybe a class called `Option` with just 2 properties a `string` and an `Action`.

3 . As I mentioned in the comments section you have redundant comments,  I'm not saying you should not explain what your code does, that's completely fine but for example here where the static polymorphism :

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a button
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private GameObject createButton(){..}

/// <summary>
/// creates a button
/// </summary>
/// <param name="button_text">The text to be displayed on the button</param>
/// <param name="function">The function to be called</param>
/// <param name="y">The local Y location of the button</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private GameObject createButton(string button_text, Action function, int y){..}
```

Your parameter names are kinda okay, even if you didn't tell me that in the summary comment I would've supposed that the parameter `button_text` which is of type `string` will probably be the text to be displayed on the button. Anyway what bothers me here is that you are doing more things behind the scenes which are left undocumented :

```
    button.tag = "Continue";
    continueButton = button;
```

This is simply removed in the second method, are you assuming that whenever no parameters are passed your button is a "Continue" button ? Perhaps that's something useful you should write in the method summary.

- Boolean variables/functions should not sound like this `clearDialogue` this looks more like a void function, i would not expect this to return a result. Maybe rename it to `IsDialogeFull` or `IsDialogOver`, you've got the idea ..

4 . If you have completed point #2 you can easily get rid of the polymorphism in the `addOptions` method just 1 single method will be enough. Just pass a single `Operation` array and iterate over it by passing into the method `createButton` the 2 properties you have, the magic numbers `-22,-48..` seems to be increasing by 26 so just start from -22 and add 26 each time, if the maximum options your window can handle is 4, just restrict it by using `if's`.

5 . You should probably be able to remove the one overload of `createButton` method using *Optional* arguments, however I'm not 100 % sure you can do that because of those lines

```
    button.tag = "Continue";
    continueButton = button;
```

6 . You can avoid using the `lock` by having a `private` constructor and a `static readonly` instance. You can read more about the different ways you can achieve the same thread-safety by reading [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) .

**Update**

- You can use method groups, which means you can pass your `Action` parameters like this : `addOptions("Yes!",iterateDialogue)` simple as that there's no need of parentheses here.
- Overall that's pretty poor OOP design. What I would've done instead :

1 . Put those in a separate class `string button_one_name, Action function_one`

```
public class DialogueOption
{
     public string ButtonText { get; private set; } 
     public Action Operation { get; private set; }

     public DialogueOption(string buttonText, Action operation)
     {
          Operation = operation;
          ButtonText = buttonText;
     }
}
```

2 . If that's all your code for the trader `private List<GameObject> trader()` that's pretty bad. NPC can do many different things they should definitely have they're own class/interface where they all inherit from.

```
public enum NPCType
{
    Merchant,
    //add more
}
public interface INPC
{
    NPCType NPCType { get; }
    DialogueOption[] Dialogue { get; }
    List<GameObject> DialogueObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Now here you should put all the things that every single npc has i.e Name,Type and some other things you might want to add, the best thing to do would be to add more interfaces or even abstract classes for the different type of NPC's for example merchants will have an extra property something like Store while the normal npc wouldn't need such a property. The `enum` is for further usage it's nice to have a idea what npc is this, the list of `gameObject` I'm not entirely sure if you will need that.

3 . The trader can become a separate class too :

```
public class TraderNPC : INPC
{
    public NPCType NPCType { get; } = NPCType.Merchant;
    public List<GameObject> DialogueObjects { get; set; }
    public DialogueOption[] Dialogue { get; } =
        {
            new DialogueOption("Hello! Welcome to the game!",)
        };
}
```

Hmm but where do we get the `Action Operation` parameter from :? Well 2 ways to go, depending on the complexity of your game. If you game is quite simple most of the NPC's will have repetitive actions - show the store, train something, etc. a complex one would be almost every single npc to have a different and unique action, this will require you to add more properties and functions into the interface `INPC` but your game at this state doesn't looks to be from the second type. In which case you can create a `public static class` to hold all of your operations.

```
public static class NPCActions
{
    //You implement these
    public static void ShowStore()
    {

    }

    public static void TrainProffession()
    {

    }

    public static void IterateDialogue()
    {

    }
}
```

Once we have this we can go back to the implementation of our Trader's `Dialogue` :

```
        public DialogueOption[] Dialogue { get; } =
        {
            new DialogueOption("Hello! Welcome to the game!", NPCActions.IterateDialogue)
        };
```

and you just keep adding new `DialogueOptions`, however I don't think this is a good dialogue design. Your npc should know the answer the user gave, once he know's that he can decide to ask him different stuff.

*Hello user would You like to buy some fruits ?*

*No* -> *Would You like to buy some vegetables than ?* -> *No* -> *You don't seem to like my shop :(*

*Yes* -> *Would you like to buy some vegetables too ?* -> *Yes* -> *You seem to like my shop :)*

That's a small explanation of what I mean, those tiny details and interactions makes bigger games feel alive and every npc will feel unique some of them will respond angry other's will be kinder.. In order to follow the result's of each answer you can add to your `INPC` interface array of `QuestionResult` which should be an enum

```
public enum QuestionResult
{
    Yes,
    No,
}
```

The more complex questions you have the more question result you should add in the `enum` you can make statistic with that array let's say if the NPC is asking for help 5 times and the user responds 3 times with **Yes** he gets a better reward else just a normal one. You can extend `DialogueOption` a lot more to fit your needs.

- One thing to note is that implementing question result's would require you to change your logic a little bit because probably that function will require some parameters and maybe even return something which isn't something an `Action` can do in which case you can go for `Predicate`, `delegate` or something else. Perhaps you might want to separate the simple blank text and the questions in a 2 classes instead of just 1 (`DialogueOption`).

4 . Your `addOptions` function can become :

```
    private GameObject addOptions(INPC currentNPC)
    {
        var parent = new GameObject();
        parent.transform.SetParent(dialogue.transform);
        int y = -22;
        foreach (DialogueOption dialogueBubble in currentNPC.Dialogue)
        {
            createButton(dialogueBubble, y).transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
            y += 26;
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

5 . You should pass `INPC` as parameter here too `findDialogue` and here as well `displayDialogue`.

6 . The variable naming was already mentioned in the question comments which you responded too so i assume you have taken a look at those. Again a lot of magic numbers avoid them at all cost, writing huge comments explaining the variables and not covering the important things is like trying to tie your shoes which are untied and torn apart .

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! This is well described and i appreciate the time you spent going over my code.  Ill start going back over my file and applying the suggestions you've given me. If you could describe point #2 more that would be awesome. I understand what it is your telling me to do, but i think they way i'm thinking of doing it would over complicate it and am curious of how you're intending to do it.

Comment: And in reference to the button.tag = "Continue";, yes its assumed that if the gameobject holds only 1 button then its the "press to continue" button. I suppose i should rename that function to createContinueButton, or something similar.

Comment: I will add some more ideas to the answer as well as clarification to point #2 when i get back home.

Comment: Thanks alot! Also  Jon Skeet's article was a good read and i am now using a static readonly variable

Comment: @Sniffle6 check out the updated answer, if you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Very nice update. That was close to how i was assuming i should do it. But your description and detail is very well thought out. I appreciate the reply and will be redoing my code to fit this format. Ill let you know if anything confuses me!

Comment: The only real question i have, is with QuestionResult. Using this method. Can i only have One result with the answer "yes". Say i have 2 separate dialogues and both have a "yes" answer. What that? And with your new DialogueOption("Hello! Welcome to the game!", NPCActions.IterateDialogue). Is also confusing. Because if hes just saying "Hello! Welcome to the game!". The game should know the continue button already exist. Therefore i shouldn't be having to pass iterateDialogue into that.. If i had the option to pass or not pass a function there so it would default pass iterateDialogue

Comment: With my previous version i can do soemthing like
text,text,2 buttons,3 buttons, text, 4 buttons, text, text. But yours seems limited?

Comment: And with my version, i can pass an AddRange to one of the functions beign called by the button to add more lines of text based off the button pressed. Which you seem to talk about and mention that yours can not do?

Comment: What do you mean by text,text,2 buttons,3 buttons, text, 4 buttons, text, text ? Is this the place where you are talking about the `AddRange` ? `range.AddRange(trader());`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/edf5f2f6ac220f3b206751fc896f068a
Notice in the gyazo, as the options are iterated threw, more buttons are displayed on screen based off the current iteration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41721/discussion-between-denis-and-sniffle6).